# Changing Data Type of Tuple Elements (PYTHON)

Tags: python, tuples

I am reading in data from a csv file and coverting it into a tuple as so,

```
text = open('States.csv').read()
lines= text.splitlines()
data= [tuple(line.split(',')) for line in lines[1:]]
data
```

Where in return I am getting my tuple printed out with all the data currently all as string:

```
[ ('Boston', 'MA', '20489', '19715', '23610', '9.9', '401', '15.6', '4499.63'),
    ('Trenton', 'NJ', '26835', '26573', '25113', '9.9', '345', '23', '552.13') ]
```

I need elements 2-4  (20489, 19715, 23610 for Boston and 26835, 26573 , 25113 for Trenton) to be integers and 5-8 to be written in as floats, how do I do this??

Comment: You would be better to use built-in library module `csv` than reading the file yourself - it handles quotation marks and values containing newlines, i.e. it will be more robust for unexpected but valid ‘csv’ content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could have:

```
types = (str, str, int, int, int, float, float, float, float)
```

Then change your:

```
data= [tuple(line.split(',')) for line in lines[1:]]
```

to:

```
data = [tuple([t(val) for t, val in zip(types, line.split(','))])
        for line in lines[1:]]
```

Trying it with these rows (after the header row):

```
Boston,MA,20489,19715,23610,9.9,401,15.6,4499.63
Trenton,NJ,26835,26573,25113,9.9,345,23,552.13
```

gives this value of `data`:

```
[('Boston', 'MA', 20489, 19715, 23610, 9.9, 401.0, 15.6, 4499.63),
 ('Trenton', 'NJ', 26835, 26573, 25113, 9.9, 345.0, 23.0, 552.13)]
```

Answer (score 0):

First try converting the tuple into list.Modify it and then change to your desired tuple.
Tuples are immutable.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution:

```
data = [ ('Boston', 'MA', '20489', '19715', '23610', '9.9', '401', '15.6', '4499.63'),
         ('Trenton', 'NJ', '26835', '26573', '25113', '9.9', '345', '23', '552.13') ]

new_t = [(*t[:2], *map(int, t[2:5]), *map(float, t[5:9])) for t in data]
print(new_t)
```

Prints:

```
[('Boston', 'MA', 20489, 19715, 23610, 9.9, 401.0, 15.6, 4499.63), 
 ('Trenton', 'NJ', 26835, 26573, 25113, 9.9, 345.0, 23.0, 552.13)]
```